# Azure Network Interface physical MAC address

Tags: networking, azure, mac-address, azure-networking

I am trying to run some third-party software on an Azure Linux VM but their licensing is tied to the MAC address. The private and public IPv4 IP addresses of the Network Interface for the VM are both static.

But, the MAC address I get starts with 00-0D and the software provider is telling me that is a "pure virtual" MAC address and will cause problems with the licensing server.

I tried to find the MAC address many different ways (looking in Azure portal > Network Interfaces > Properties > MAC Address, running `ifconfig` on the VM, using Powershell command `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName %rgName%`) but all give the same result.

How can I get the "physical" MAC address of my VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VM (Virtual Machine), it will NOT have a physical MAC address.

You will need to go back to the vendor and tell them that is the only MAC address the machine has.

Comment: We are just trying to re-create what we had on AWS where the MAC address started 02:F8 and vendor did not make the same complaint that it was "pure virtual" (I'm not sure what determines pure virtual or not, it seems the leading 0's).

Comment: This might be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/40712/what-range-of-mac-addresses-can-i-safely-use-for-my-virtual-machines

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that discusses how to assign a second NIC to the VM and assign your own MAC address to the NIC from within the OS (Windows): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/understanding-static-mac-address-licensing-in-azure/ba-p/1386187.

Use one of the locally administered MAC ranges to create your own MAC address.